# Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available

Tags: hadoop, hbase

when i want to start base shell i get this error :

```
[main] Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
```

like this :

```
root@SE ~ # ./hbase/bin/hbase shell
2015-02-15 20:17:51,925 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.98.10-hadoop2, rb18bc4b06f3eb90f592c906e78fb6461548ae627, Sun Feb  1 05:48:33 UTC 2015

hbase(main):001:0>
```

how should i fix this error ?

Comment: just change your configration file. Find the `hadoop.native.lib` key, change to `io.native.lib.available` . And I think this is just a warning.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue of Hbase. It has been [tracked here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-5554) and the status shows it is fixed in newer versions.

The Hbase operation is not affected. There is even a tutorial on Hbase that includes these warnings as normal and includes them in the expected outputs:
[HBase Basics.](https://www.rubyplus.com/articles/901)